# Adding name of FeatureClasses to names of joined fields using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, fields-attributes, attribute-joins

Using ArcPy, how do I add the name of FeatureClasses to the names of the joined fields?

This is my code which I think helps explain what I am looking for.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
fc = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
featureList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
field_names = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(fc)]
for feature in featureList:
    fields = ["AAAA"]
    arcpy.JoinField_management("BATI", "ID_BATI", feature, "ID_BATI", fields)
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

[image]

---

I modified my code by integrating (arcpy.env.qualifiedFieldNames = True) in my code and replace arcpy.JoinField_management by arcpy.AddJoin_management, but I have this error.

ExecuteError: ERROR 999999: Error during the execution of the function.
Failure to execute (AddJoin).

I think the error comes from the loop on feature, but I do not know how to correct it.

---

```
import arcpy
# Set environment settings
arcpy.env.workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
arcpy.env.qualifiedFieldNames = True
# Set local variables
FcCible = "BATI"
featurelayer = "Batijoin"
IDjoin = "ID_BATI"
joinTable = "fc2"
# Create a feature layer from the BATI featureclass
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(FcCible, featurelayer)
featureList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
for feature in featureList:
    joinTable = feature
    arcpy.AddJoin_management(featurelayer, IDjoin, joinTable, IDjoin)
# Copy the layer to a new permanent feature class
outFeature = "atest.gdb/Batijoin"
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(featurelayer, outFeature)
```

---

Answer (score 0):

To do this I think your code needs to involve the use of the [Alter Field (Data Management)](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/alter-field-properties.htm) tool which:

> Renames fields and field aliases, or alters field properties.

Alternatively, you can use a sequence of Add Field (to get a new field with your chosen name), Calculate Field (to move the contents of your old field to the new one) and Delete Field (to delete the old field).

One thing I am not certain of without testing is whether you will be able to include a period/dot (.) in you new field names so be prepared to try an underscore (_) instead.

Comment: OP absolutely will **not** be able to add a dot to a fieldname.

Comment: after research in the forums, and the documentation of ArcGIS pro : Add Join (Data Management) and Maintain fully qualified field name, I must put (arcpy.env.qualifiedFieldNames = True) in my code. but the output field name still does not include the featureClasses names.